# Chrome/Safari: box-shadow only appears on text input if border is specified

Tags: google-chrome, css, safari, webkit

I'm running into a problem with WebKit browsers (Chrome 15.0.x and Safari 5.1.1) where box shadows are not being rendered on text inputs.  Just by chance, I discovered that explicitly setting the border causes the box shadow to render, even if you set the border to 'none' or the default, 'inset'.  The code below (view it in action on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maddestofprops/TKKm4/)) demonstrated the problem when viewed with Chrome or Safari, but it renders as expected in Firefox 6.0.2 and Opera 11.52.

HTML

```
<input type="text" value="Works" style="border:none;" />
<input type="text" value="Works" style="border:inset;" />
<input type="text" value="Doesn't" />
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"] {
    margin: 1em;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px green;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px green;
}
```

Am I missing some detail of using box shadows in WebKit or have I found a bug?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`input`s, in WebKit, have this property applied to them by default:

```
-webkit-appearance: textfield;
```

This is what you want if you want the appearance of the text field to be platform-dependent. Sometimes you can style it with this still set, but other times, it needs to be set to `none`, which makes it apply standard CSS and rely less on the operating system. It seems `border` automatically triggers this, but `box-shadow` does not, yet `box-shadow` is only applied if `-webkit-appearance` is `none`. (the fact that the platform-dependent appearance is not turned off if `box-shadow` is applied and that `box-shadow` is not rendered if the platform-dependent appearance is enabled may be a bug)

To fix this, simply explicitly tell it to not use the platform-dependent appearance:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

**[Test it](http://jsfiddle.net/TKKm4/8/) with `-webkit-appearance: none;` added.**

The downside of this is you lose (some of) the platform's native look, but if you're trying to use `box-shadow`, you might be trying to style away the native look anyways.

Comment: Wow, that's an obscure property.  :)  But it does the trick for text inputs and the loss of system-specific styling is okay.  Select boxes are kind of different though.  They become pretty unpresentable using -webkit-appearance:none and I wasn't able to find another value that looks any better.  And unlike text inputs, specifying a border on a select doesn't trigger any change that causes the shadow to render.  I think this may be a bug