# How to fade out all elements except focused element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not good in front end. But now I need to write some jQuery. What I want to do is I have a text box. It has many parents element including HTML body tag. What I want to do is I want to change all the color a little dark with opacity for the rest of elements except that text box when it is focused.

The fading is something like modal box in Bootstrap. How can I achieve that?

Comment: can you share your work ?

Comment: Post some `html` too..

Comment: even if you are not good, you should post some code

Comment: Try and think of this a little differently. It's a lot easier to add an fixed positioned 'overlay' div with .7 opacity (for example) that covers all elements apart from the textbox - achieved with a z-index, than to literally set the opacity of each individual element.

Comment: You NEED to provide code dude!!

Answer (score 7):

you could add a huge `box-shadow` (`100vmax` is enough to cover all the viewport), maybe with a short transition, to the `input` element when it receives focus, e.g.

```
input {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, 0);
  transition: 1s box-shadow
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, .7);
}
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjpqjg

When the input loses the focus, the effect disappears with the same duration.

---

Note: On Safari this effect based on `box-shadow` doesn't work [unless you set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199095/chrome-safari-box-shadow-only-appears-on-text-input-if-border-is-specified) `-webkit-appearance: none;`, but you might use an `outline` instead (tested on Version 9.0 (9537.86.1.56.2)/MacOS 10.9.5)

```
input {
  outline: 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, 0) solid;
  -webkit-transition: 1s outline;
  transition: 1s outline;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, .7) solid;
}
```

Codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjpqRb

Comment: Who else would think about using box-shadow???!... This is simple and great effect. Just can you explain why second one isn't darky? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOpLbx

Comment: Nice approach! Didn't think of this. The only (tiny - and slightly irrelevant) issue would be it's compatibility problem with IE8: http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow - same with transition.

Comment: Yes but IE8 has a really low market share, and in the worst case, the page still works when this property and vh/vw units are not supported.  - @A.Wolff I see both the input with the shadow

Comment: Nice! Works great with chrome. For some reason it does not work on Safari (even 9) though. Even prefixes didn't fixed it.

Comment: I'm the only one to get issue with any other following inputs not shadowed:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvpyod  (even setting `z-index`) (tested on chrome)

Comment: Nice! Apparently there is a bug or something with box-shadow and input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199095/chrome-safari-box-shadow-only-appears-on-text-input-if-border-is-specified. Maybe related. But `outline` bypassed it! Well played.

Comment: @QuentinRoy None of fixes  solves it for me, using outline or -webkit-appearence  :(  EDIT: using `display: block;` and outline (as suggested) fix it but an input shouldn't be a block, so... :(

Comment: Just brilliant! Here is my 50 cents :).
If you want to highlight group of elements which contains input (i.e. search line with button for example) - you could apply these classes to the outer div and use :focus-within selector to activate onfocus behaviour. For example:
#search_form>div {
  outline: 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, 0) solid;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all;
  transition: 1s all;
}

#search_form>div:focus-within {
  outline: 100vmax rgba(0,0,0, .5) solid;
}